# What is a word that describes the environmental products of human activity?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

My business is inventing and producing more sustainable solutions for the use of energy, water, food and materials, that are consumed in the course of living and working  in domestic, commercial and industrial premises (locations where people congregate), plus the treatment and disposal of waste streams from the activities carried out in those locations. The Ecological Footprint of a building is a measure of how much area of biologically productive land, water and air the building requires to produce all the resources the people in it consume and to also absorb the waste generated.

The word I am looking for will describe the collective energy and matter that flows to and from the natural environment as a result of human activity in a location. The collective inputs and outputs or "products of human activity" so to speak.

Wikipedia uses the word Anthropogenic Impact in a discussion of human impacts on the environment [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_impact_on_the_environment). I also found the word Biocapacity in a related glossary at [Footprint Network](https://www.footprintnetwork.org/resources/glossary/), but nothing close to what I need.

The best I can come up with is "Products of Anthropological Impact" (PAI). I would use the word as follows; "The system is designed to reduce 'PAI' through a smarter understanding of how humans go about their daily activities and optimise the 'PAI' for various classes of activity".

A compound word or phrase would be acceptable.